# How to add comments to Drupal 7 in PHP using Drupal Services Module

Tags: php, drupal-7, drupal-modules

As far as I know, [Drupal Services Module](http://drupal.org/project/services) can allow PHP scripts to communicate with Drupal  7. But how to add a comment to a post using this module?

Example will be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at my answer here:

[Creating comments and nodes with Services 3.x and JSON][1]


  [1]: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22277/creating-comments-and-nodes-with-services-3-x-and-json/30123#30123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the testcode that does exactly that

http://drupalcode.org/project/services.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-3.x:/tests/functional/ServicesResourceCommentTests.test#l100